# How do I create a schema in another DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, schema

I am trying to create a schema in a new DB I have created.

sqlComand:

```
   exec('use ADD6_DATA; exec sp_executesql N''create schema 1M'' ')
```

But i get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '1'.

I execute the statement from c#:

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object names that begin with a numeric *must* be delimit identified. There's also no need for a "dynamic" statement here. The `USE` shouldn't be there if this is coming from your application too, as it (the application) should be connecting to the appropriate database (`ADD6_DATA`) in the connection string. So you statement simply becomes:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA [1M];
```

Ideally, therefore, don't use this schema name, as *all* references would require the schema be delimit identified. It is (normally) recommended that you use object names that don't require delimit identification to avoid such errors as above. Some (older) systems don't (properly) quote object names which can cause them to have difficulty referencing objects that need to be delimit identified as well.

Comment: Personally, I recommend following [regular identifier naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15#rules-for-regular-identifiers). Adding that one can avoud the `USE` statement with: `sqlCommand = "EXEC ADD6_DATA..sp_executesql N'create schema [1M]';";`

Comment: True on the alternative to the `USE` , @DanGuzman , it's more that it appears the OP is running the above from their C# application, so the connection string *should* be connecting to the correct database in the first place; therefore redeclaring the database in the SQL statement is effectively redundant. Adding the fact that they then put that in an `EXEC` with a further `EXEC sys.sp_executesql` is quite odd.

Comment: I wish the docs on creating schemas had had 1 example of the square brackets!

Comment: @DanGuzman So dbName..sp_executesql, means run the sp_executesql command for DBName? That much nicer!

Comment: It doesn't need to, @ManInMoon , as the identification rules for objects is in the documentation Guzman linked to. Those rules don't apply to just schemas, it applies to all identifiers in SQL Server. That could be the name of a Database, Function, Table, and includes Aliases, etc, etc.

Comment: @ManInMoon, yes, when one database-qualifies a system stored procedure, it executes in the context of the specified database.